# using ui.router to dynamic load pages

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm a newbie in `AngularJS`, and I was using `ui.router`.
What I am trying to do is load `html` from different portals, like:

```
/s3/home
/goo/home
/gle/home
```

All prefix like `s3`, `goo`, `gle` are from backend, I have to get it first then load my pages, any idea for this, any way to put a variable in relative path, like

```
/{{portal}}/home
```

**Mockup for expression:**

```
angular.module('app')
.config(function ($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('{{portal}}.home', { //portal from backend
            url: '/',
            views: {
                'content@': {
                    templateUrl: 'scripts/app/{{portal}}/home.html', //portal from backend
                    controller: 'MainController'
                }
            }
        });
})
```

Find a way to do it, dynamic templateURL will do the same thing
http://fredparke.com/blog/angularjs-directive-dynamic-template

Comment: you can put variables anywhere you like in the html files. Your question needs clarity though and more code to make sense at all of what you are trying to do

Comment: I want to use it in Javascript, is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to use it in Javascript, is it possible

No i'm afraid not. Use Curly braces to bind expressions to elements in your html. I think you need to rethink more fundamentally your application and why you want to have "variable" template urls in such a way. Try and read up on REST as that's probably what you want to have for your backend. The frontend can then parameterise requests via url/query parameters